# Objective-C: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 when stepping through a double* array

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

In my init, I setup the following:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Time-Domain Wavelet pitch detection setup
        self.bufferCapacity = 2048;
        self.index = 0;
        dataBuffer = (SInt16*)malloc(self.bufferCapacity * sizeof(SInt16));
        dywapBuffer = (double*)malloc(self.bufferCapacity * sizeof(double));
        dywapitch_inittracking(&pitchtracker);
    }
    return self;
}
```

In a callback, I try to do the following:

```
    SInt16 *dataBuffer = THIS->dataBuffer;
    double *dywapBuffer = THIS->dywapBuffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < THIS.bufferCapacity; i++)
    {
        double* doublePointer = dywapBuffer + (i * sizeof(double));
        SInt16* intPointer = dataBuffer + (i * sizeof(SInt16));
        *doublePointer = (double)(*intPointer);
    }
    double frequency = dywapitch_computepitch(&THIS->pitchtracker, dywapBuffer, 0, frames);
```

However, when the for loop reaches i = 256, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 when it tries to assign doublePointer. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SInt16 *dataBuffer = THIS->dataBuffer;
double *dywapBuffer = THIS->dywapBuffer;
for (int i = 0; i < THIS.bufferCapacity; i++)
{
    // compiler will do the pointer arithmetic correctly for you
    double* doublePointer = dywapBuffer + i;
    SInt16* intPointer = dataBuffer + i;
    *doublePointer = (double)(*intPointer);
}
double frequency = dywapitch_computepitch(&THIS->pitchtracker, dywapBuffer, 0, frames);
```

you don't need to something like `dywapBuffer + (i * sizeof(double))` because it makes no sense. compiler know the type of `dywapBuffer` is `double *`, so `dywapBuffer + 1` will increase the address by `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: As further explanation, you are going out of bounds because `sizeof(double)` will be 8.  256 * 8 = 2048 (out of bounds).